# IMO problems, can someone help me to learn problem solving skills?

Tags: problem-solving

I am a student and I want to enhance my problem-solving abilities of maths-problems.

I am Italian and I try to resolve the national problems (of course of my country) and I have some difficulty in solving them but I bought a maths-puzzles-book (Engel problem solving strategy) and I want to study it.

My question is can anyone who is able to solve IMO problems can teach my few things to reach my goal?

p.s.
For now I absolutely can not approach at the IMO problems, I have some difficulty to resolve the Italian national bracket problems.

Comment: Art of problem solving is a dedicated community for cracking Olympiad.

Comment: The Engel book is a very good book. Stay with it, and don't rush it. There is no magic bullet. Just work hard, smart and steady. Stay away from the harder IMO problems until you've mastered the levels before that, so as to maintain confidence.